# grep -v (invert match) matching word and line following match. -A -B not working

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cygwin

I would like to format output of the loop of command which checks correction of DNS settings of two domains across 12 dns servers `for i in {1..12} ; do nslookup hostname1.fqdn ns$i.provider.fqdn; nslookup hostname2.fqdn ns$i.provider,fqdn ; done"`

The standard output looks like:

```
Server: ns1.provider.fqdn
Address: 10.11.12.13

Name: hostname1.fqdn
Address: 172.21.37.1

Server: ns1.provider.fqdn
Address: 10.11.12.13

Name: hostname2.fqdn
Address: 172.21.37.1

Server: ns2.provider.fqdn
Address: 10.11.12.13

Name: hostname1.fqdn
Address: 172.21.37.1

Server: ns2.provider.fqdn
Address: 10.11.12.13

Name: hostname2.fqdn
Address: 172.21.37.1
```

I would like to chop it to the following form:

```
DNS: ns1.provider.fqdn HOST: hostname1.fqdn IP: 172.21.37.1
DNS: ns1.provider.fqdn HOST: hostname2.fqdn IP: 172.21.37.1
DNS: ns2.provider.fqdn HOST: hostname1.fqdn IP: 172.21.37.1
DNS: ns2.provider.fqdn HOST: hostname2.fqdn IP: 172.21.37.1
```

But in the way to create such form of output I've stuck with grep inverted match (-v) does not work with -A and -B commands, which would allow me to grep out first 3 lines of each nslookup output and add `echo DNS: ns$i.provider.fqdn"` and, after that, a few `sed`'s to format final output. Or should I go the other way, to put nslookup output into a variable (or array) and simply echo its contents? Or do it with sed/awk somehow?

The main question is how to "emulate" behavior of `grep sth -A 3`  but with `-v` - `grep -v -A 3 sth` - I've already tried with `grep -vE "Server:  ns[0-9]{1,2}.provider\nAddress"` but \n is not working :(

Comment: Are you asking about -A and -B not working with grep -v __or__ are you asking about how to convert nslookup output to one line? These are _completely_ different questions.  Are you asking XY question? Why not write an awk or bash script to get the data from nslookup and output it in a format you want? Or write an awk or bash or even sed script to convert the whole output to the format you want and forget that grep ever existed?

Comment: I've come to this problem and I'm thinking how to format it that way, and I think, that grep would be easiest solution... But I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 2):

With any POSIX `awk` you could pipe the output of your loop to `awk` (`... done | awk ...`) with the following `awk` script:

```
awk -v RS='' ' NR%2==1 {s=$2} NR%2==0 {print "DNS: " s " HOST: " $2 " IP: " $4}'
```

An empty string as the value of the record separator (`RS`) indicates that records are separated by one or more blank lines.

Comment: This returns nothing in my termux :( Mayby awk is somehow broken in it?

Comment: @AdamG To make Renaud's answer working, you could pipe the output from `nslookup` through `dos2unix` first.  `nslookup ... | dos2unix | awk ....`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, you're right, I thought that empty `RS` was a GNU extension but I just checked and it is indeed POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '
                      { sub("\r$", "") }
$1 == "Server:"       { n = 0; printf("DNS: %s ", $2) }
$1 == "Name:"         { n = 1; printf("HOST: %s ", $2) }
$1 == "Address:" && n { print $2 }
'
```

If you want the columns to align, set the minimum length of the `DNS` and `HOST` columns. Here I've selected `30` for both. You'll have to set those to the longest `DNS` and longst `HOST` respectively:

```
awk '
                      { sub("\r$", "") }
$1 == "Server:"       { n = 0; printf("DNS: %-30s ", $2) }
$1 == "Name:"         { n = 1; printf("HOST: %-30s ", $2) }
$1 == "Address:" && n { print $2 }
'
```

The line `{ sub("\r$", "") }` removes `\r` last on the line from the output of the Windows version of `nslookup`.

Comment: let's say the hostname is longer than hostname1, and it's hostnamehostname1 - it has generated such an output:
`    127.21.37.1tname1.fqdn`
`    127.21.37.1tname2.fqdn`
`    127.21.37.1tname1.fqdn`
`    127.21.37.1tname2.fqdn`
Is it fault of non-posix awk in cygwin?

Comment: @AdamG I can't see the formatting of that here in the comments unfortunately. If they have different length, the columns will be squiggly. I added an alternative to the answer. Does that look better?

Comment: the output looks like to be overwritten line after line with preserving previous, longer strings, but still it looks like recreating each line from begging...

Comment: like with GNU version - works like a charm in linux :) Looks like cygwin has broken awk, shame :(

Comment: @AdamG Ok, I didn't know you used Cygwin with the Windows version of `nslookup`. I updated the answer. It's not awk that is broken. It's that the output from Windows binaries tend to have a `\r\n` line ending.

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) provides a language for transforming multi-line text in readable ways.

```
$ txr nslookup.txr data
DNS: ns1.provider.fqdn HOST: hostname1.fqdn IP: 172.21.37.1
DNS: ns1.provider.fqdn HOST: hostname2.fqdn IP: 172.21.37.1
DNS: ns2.provider.fqdn HOST: hostname1.fqdn IP: 172.21.37.1
DNS: ns2.provider.fqdn HOST: hostname2.fqdn IP: 172.21.37.1
```

Code:

```
@(repeat)
Server: @dns
Address: @nil

Name: @host
Address: @ip
@  (output)
DNS: @dns HOST: @host IP: @ip
@  (end)
@(end)
```

In Vim, highlighting shows us what is meta and what is literal:

[image: Code syntax colored by Vim]